# Placing text box buttons in SVG rect

Tags: svg

Is it possible to place a button/input text box in a SVG rect. I want to create a flowchart like display, where in each step user needs to enter some values in the text box and click button to proceed further as per the values entered. I tried finding it but couldn't find any thing relevant.

Any information/pointers/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could create a foreignObject sibling of the rect (i.e. not a child) position it over the rect and then create html input controls as childtrn of the foreignObject.

Comment: I created a foreign object within <svg></svg>. And it works. I guess this will be child?